# aws ec2: Recently I got high-rate 1/2 checks passed, how can I find what's wrong with my instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 4 t3.micro instances running. They are running fine at beginning. But after a few days, 2 of them got "1/2 checks passed" issue. I have to stop and start the instances and they running again. And then after another few days, 3 of them got "1/2 checks passed" issue. Stop&Start instances solved.

The fail rate is really high. How can I check what wrong with the instances?

Answer (score 0):

As per AWS Documentation  instance status check may fail due to the following reason:

Failed system status checks

Incorrect networking or startup configuration

Exhausted memory

Corrupted file system

Incompatible 

You can view status check through the console in the status check tab.

For resolving the issue go through below link describing Troubleshooting Instances with Failed Status Checks:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html#InitialSteps